# How can I put the output from Get-SBFarmStatus into an easily accessible object?

Tags: powershell, servicebus, psobject

I am trying to test the result of running `Get-SBFarmStatus` for failures. The output of the command *looks* like a nicely-formatted PSObject, but it's some kind of weird MS formatted string:

```sh
> $result

HostId HostName                            ServiceName                   Status 
------ --------                            -----------                   ------ 
     1 NVSDRELSBS12330.discoverready.local Service Bus Gateway           Running
     1 NVSDRELSBS12330.discoverready.local Service Bus Message Broker    Running
     1 NVSDRELSBS12330.discoverready.local Service Bus Resource Provider Running
     1 NVSDRELSBS12330.discoverready.local Service Bus VSS               Running
     1 NVSDRELSBS12330.discoverready.local FabricHostSvc                 Running

> $result.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                          
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                          
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

> $result.Status
   #  <-- nothing returned

> $result | select *


ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280
pageHeaderEntry                         : 
pageFooterEntry                         : 
autosizeInfo                            : 
shapeInfo                               : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo
groupingEntry                           : 

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3
shapeInfo                               : 
groupingEntry                           : 

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

etc etc
```

How can parse this data into an easily-accessible object?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the existence of `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo` in your output I'd guess `$result` is populated by `Format-*` output. Remove any `Format-*` commands as they are only intended for host output.